# Send phpsession and cookie from program to browser

Tags: c#, cookies, browser

I've written the program which parses web site information (it logs in to sites and makes parse under phpsession). Can I send phpsession and cookie from HttpWebRequest to my desktop browser and open any web page with post parameters?

Comment: Technically you may take all the cookies and set them in browser. Practically it won't always work.

Comment: You can add the Session id as Get Parameter to the URL ?`PHPSESSID=the_id`. But thats really unsecure and hopfully doesent work with most webpages